# Chroot command for a Ruby process

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, sinatra, chroot

Having the following `app.rb` Ruby application:

```
#!/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.3.0/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/pwd' do
  `pwd`
end
```

I'm able to start it as a webserver with a command such as:

- `./Users/doug/code/backdore/app.rb`
- `ruby /Users/doug/code/backdore/app.rb`
- `/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.3.0/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby /Users/doug/code/backdore/app.rb`

Then, using a webclient, a GET on `http://localhost:4567/pwd` can return `/Users/doug/code/backdore` which is the current path from where I started the command.

If I stop the server, and execute again the command from `Users/doug/code/` folder, then the returned path from the server is gonna be: `/Users/doug/code`.

My question is the following, because I would like to *chroot* this webserver, I would need to prefix the command with something like:

```
sudo chroot /Users/doug/code/backdore /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.3.0/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby "app.rb"
```

However, this donesn't work and I have this error message:

> chroot: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.3.0/versions/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

I'm working on Mac OS X, but I suppose this should be similar on Ubuntu. How could I chroot this server inside '`/Users/doug/code/backdore`', in order to see only '`/`' from the server?

**Edit**

In order to have a Ruby interpreter inside the chroot, I just installed [mruby](http://geekmonkey.org/articles/36-an-introduction-to-mini-ruby) and made some tests with this script...

```
$ cat test/script.rb
loop do
  puts "hello world"
end
```

My current location is:

```
$ pwd
/Users/doug/code/mruby
```

So, just for testing the script,

```
$ bin/mruby test/script.rb
hello world
hello world
hell^C
```

It's working fine. But if I try to chroot this like this:

```
$ chroot /Users/doug/code/mruby bin/mruby test/script.rb
chroot: /Users/doug/code/mruby: Operation not permitted
```

And if I try like this:

```
$ sudo chroot /Users/doug/code/mruby bin/mruby test/script.rb
Password:
~/code/mruby ‹1.9.3-p194›  ‹master*› $
```

and nothing happen (it should be an infinit loop).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

When running a process under chroot, **all** of the binaries, libraries, and other files used by the process must be available under its new root directory. Since `/usr/local/Cellar` does not exist under `/Users/doug/code/backdore` (*e.g,* as `/Users/doug/code/backdore/usr/local/Cellar`!), the `exec` run by the `chroot` command fails.

Trying to run a Ruby application under chroot will be pretty painful, honestly, because it'll end up requiring a ton of libraries (both Ruby and otherwise). You may be better off having your process chroot itself after it starts up, as that'll bypass most of the library issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @duskwuff. I just added an other example with a chrootable mruby binary, living in the same parent folder as a script. However, I have the same errors...

Comment: `chroot` requires root access -- you can't ever run it as non-root. Without knowing what `test/script.rb` is, I couldn't say what the problem is with the second script.